# Please help me with my harmonic droing/humming/buzzing sounds on my Toyota Camry 2011

Tags: noise

Just for context: I hit a huge pothole while going 70 mph. The rims were completely bent on the right side and 2 of my tires were ripped (Both on the right side). After replacing the tires, i hear this intense rubbing sound that starts at 45, gets very loud at 60, and intense at 70. It quiets down when I hit 80.

What I did:

I replaced the bent wheels. (Soon after, one of them was slightly bent again)

- Realigned my tires.
- Rebalanced my tires.
- Replaced wheel bearing/hub
- Checked transmission (The place said it was fine)

The sound is still there.

Here's the link for the video of the sound (Turn volume way up)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/AeKoR.jpg

I have no idea what i should do next, and desperate for a solution. Please help:

Answer (score 0):

In the video the transmission is in Drive. Downshift one gear lower and repeat the experiment. If the sound now starts well below 45, gets very loud well below 60, intense well below 70 and disappears well below 80, then the sound is related to engine speed, not road speed. In that case, it's not a suspension issue, it's an engine or drivetrain issue.

To me it sounds like an exhaust leak. The extreme shock could have cracked a weld in the exhaust system or torn a weak spot. A smoke machine connected to the exhaust pipe can quickly locate such a leak if you can't find it visually.

Comment: So mine is an automatic... What would be a gear lower than D?  Thank you so much!

Comment: @bok0426 Something like "L" or "1" or "2" is likely how it's labeled.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica Tried it! The sound appears in the same mph as Drive. Nothing changed ;( Any other options?

Comment: What you have learned is that the noise, whatever it is, is indeed related to the rotation of the wheels. So it's nothing to do with the engine, or the exhaust system (sorry, @MTA).

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica  Damn, maybe they fixed the wrong wheel bearing?

Answer (score 0):

You have determined that the noise is directly related to the car's speed, so it must be tires and/or wheels and/or CV joints and/or wheel bearings. Something (or several somethings) is worn or damaged.

You'll need to have a capable mechanic examine the car. Perhaps or more of the tires are damaged or defective (remember that even new tires are sometimes defective). Perhaps one or more of the replacement wheels are damaged. Perhaps one or more of the wheel hubs (you said you replaced one...there are three others) is bent or damaged. Same for wheel bearings.

Comment: hm, there are 4 wheel bearings as well?

Comment: Yes, one at each wheel. In addition, as a front-wheel drive vehicle, there will also be constant-velocity U-joints in the front between the transmission and the wheels. Either of those CV joints (there's usually one on each side) could also be worn or defective and cause the noise.

Comment: Im going back to the mechanic on monday, I think he fixed the wrong bearings considering the noise hasn't changed at all. I will update you! Thank you so much